# Is this script vulnerable to shell command bypass?

Tags: php, linux, shell, security, file-upload

I'm using this script to receive base 64 encoded images from an Android app. I was wondering if there's any way possible to bypass a PHP shell command inside a POST request and get it to work in the server, for example, sending the command shell encoded and a name like "shell.php", "shell.php%0delete0". According to the script, everything will be saved as .png, so I'd say it's safe, but maybe I'm wrong and the script is actually vulnerable to shell command uploads.

```
<?php 
header('charset=utf-8');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        file_put_contents("/var/www/html/admigas/android/uploads/$name".strval(date('_Ym')).".png",base64_decode($image));
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong params";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nothing to do";
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you saying you are going to send the name of the script to be run from the app? If so, do not do it. If you really want to, make sure you use prepared statements, sanitize the input really well and still don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's look at the code step-by-step. My comments are preceded by `#`:

```
<?php 
header('charset=utf-8');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
        # This is provided by the user:
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        # This is provided by the user:
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        # Where does $name come from? User input, of course!
        file_put_contents("/var/www/html/admigas/android/uploads/$name".strval(date('_Ym')).".png",base64_decode($image));
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong params";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nothing to do";
}
```

Consequently, sending `name=../../../../reverse-shell.php%00` with a base64-encoded payload will allow an attacker to upload an arbitrary file (in this case, PHP code), and probably execute it on the subsequent PHP request.

Solution (presented in diff format):

```
-           $name = $_POST['name'];
+           $name = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]#', '', $_POST['name']);
```

You definitely want to remove any non-URL-safe characters to prevent attacks. You may want to [totally rethink your strategy, of course](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files).

Comment: I've sent a POST request with Fiddler using these parameters name=reverse-shell.php%00&image=PD9waHAgDQplY2hvICJIZWxsbyI7DQo/Pg== but I get the response: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 8

Comment: There's some weirdness with `NUL` byte handling on different versions of PHP and different operating systems. Generally, you should assume it's vulnerable unless you know for sure it isn't.

Comment: Also: Apache mod_mime and multiple filename extensions.